# Смещение css картинки при нажатии

Tags: css

Что нужно сделать чтобы бекграундовая картинка смещалась на 1~2px винз при нажатии по ней?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно при нажатии на элемент устанавливать свойство css background-position в соответствующее значение.

- [Можно сделать на яваскрипте](http://jsfiddle.net/aZyZa/)
- [Можно сделать на css](http://jsfiddle.net/aZyZa/1/)

Comment: CSS няшней будет, ясно дело. Хотя я не уверен, что свойство `:active` валидно для чего-то кроме `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body{
background: fixed #FFFFFF url(../images/bg0.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
var n=0;
document.body.onclick=function(){n++;body.style.background="fixed #FFFFFF url(../images/bg0.jpg) "+n+"px "+n+"px no-repeat";}
</script>
```

Comment: вообще ничего не отображается в html документе